# transaction isolation level code issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have following java code to set up a oracle connection:

```
private static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException, PublishException { 
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
String url = PublishingProperties.getDBConnString(); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,PublishingProperties.getDBUser(),PublishingProperties.getDBPassword()); 
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
stmt.exec("alter session set currenct_schema=abc"); 
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE); 
conn.setAutoCommit(false); 
conn.setReadOnly(true); 
return conn; 
}
```

I always get "ora-08177" exception. I have read some articles and wanted to change isolation level to "Read only", which is only available in oracle. Is this the right direction to solve 08177 issue? If it is, should I get rid of following code:

```
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE); 
conn.setReadonly(true);
```

from above and put following code instead?

```
stmt.exec("ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL READONLY");
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes the reason I want to try "readonly" is to get rid of "08177". I had tried to change it to "read committed" and it worked well however read consistency is compromised. Since the connection is read only (note: this is different than isolation level readonly), I am confused with why I am still getting "08177".

Comment: No, I don't want to change the data. Sorry I had a mistake in my question. I think

Comment: No, I don't want to change the data. I tried "readonly" isolation level. According to "asktom" [link] (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html), it is the same as "serializable" except the transaction will be read only. But it turns out to be different!

Comment: My transaction is "readonly". And I still got "08177" in the code, here is one article I searched: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CDF9F17E-C6EF-4E2A-A027-6AF6CE8195BC@phlo.org

Trace stack is big and I want to reproduce the issue so that I can get more specific trace file.